# Merge inner parameter struct when using template - azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a lot of default parameters in my template. I want to categorize them.

```
# template.yml
parameters:
  azure:
    name: cargo_test              # Default job name
    displayName: Cargo test       # Default displayName
    condition: true               # Job condition
    strategy:                     # Default strategy to test on Windows, MacOs and Linux.
      matrix:
       Linux:
         vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
       MacOS:
         vmImage: macOS-10.13
       Windows:
         vmImage: vs2017-win2016
  name: job_name
  default_parameter1: default1
  default_parameter2: defualt2
  # rest of code
```

```
- job:A
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    azure:
      name: test_name
```

This cause `parameter.azure` contains only one field `name`. I want to overwrite `parameters.azure.name` not all `parameters.azure` struct. Is it possible in azure pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to overwrite azure.name not all azure struct.

It seems that you are worrying if you just overwrite one parameter in `.yml` file which is using other `template.yml` file, it will affect all azure struct, right?

If so, you don't need worry about this. As what you defined in `template.yml` file, it has lots of parameters. After you use it in other `.yml` file: `name: test_name` , it only overwrite the value of parameter **name** with no effect on other parameters, and also this overwrite only available on current job.

For example, if in your `use-template.yml`:

```
- job:A
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    azure:
      name: test_name
- job:B
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    azure:
      condition: failed()
```

The overwriting of `name`, will only affect this parameter(`name`) value in Job `A`. **After** Job `A` finished, the value of name will reback to `cargo_test` in Job `B`.

In one word, the configuration in **template.yml** is fixed, the used in other `yml` will have any affect to the `template.yml`. So, you don't need to worry about how to categorize parameters which we does not support it until now.

You can check this simple example in official doc: [Job templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#job-templates).If have any misunderstanding about your idea, just feel free to correct me.

**Updated:**

Since we can get the value with `parameters.azure.name`, the Azure Devops should support these parameters categorize. And also, after tested, I got the same result with you. If overwrite `parameters.azure.name`, the rest parameters which in the same level with `parameters.azure.name` are all empty. I think this should be a **issue** which need our Product Group to fix it.

I have raise this issue report on our official Developer Community: [When I overwrite the template parameter, the value be empty](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/713416/when-i-overwrite-the-template-parameter-the-value.html). You can follow this ticket, so that you can get the notification once it has any updated.

In addition, it seems no other work around to achieve parameters categorize. Just patience for this issue fixed. Once the fixed script release, our engineer would inform it in that ticket.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I understand that each job is separate. The problem is that if I overwrite `parameters.name` it will NOT change `parameters.default_parameter1` to be empty. 

If I overwrite `parameters.azure.name` it will overwrite whole `parameters.azure` I would like to overwrite just `parameters.azure.name` and rest of fields (like `parameters.azure.condition`) should stay default - but they are empty. Hope now it's more clear.

Comment: I have the same result with you. The Azure Devops should support this categorize, since we can get the value with `parameters.azure.name`. I have raised this issue report ticket in our official forum, you can track that to get the latest message from Product Group. I have updated the details info in my answer, please check it.